# What are some new technical developments in operating systems?

Tags: operating-system

I need to investigate some new technical developments in operating systems. What would be some interesting developments to write about?

I am looking at any interesting development within the last 5 years and have only come across Azure Sphere

I expect to write about 3 or 4 examples of new technical developments in operating systems

Comment: This question is going to get closed as non-programming. For us olde timers, operating systems are much worse than they used to be. Things that have gone by the wayside include multiple processor levels (not just user/kernel); standardized error messages; batch processing; printer queue management; and concern for security (e.g. secure) management of shared libraries). The only major improvement that I have over the past 30 years is thread support. Much of the rest has been downhill (and don't get me started on programming languages).

Answer (score 1):

I've spent almost 20 years looking for something that's truly new (for operating systems); and the only thing that I can think of that's recent is the Spectre (and Meltdown) security disaster and associated mitigations.

Almost everything else is the same old ideas regurgitated/reimplemented with fresh marketing hype. For an example (your example) consider Azure Sphere - a low budget/low effort attempt at recycling an existing kernel (Linux, which itself is/was a reimplementation of a crusty lump of memorabilia from late 1960s) where the main technical achievement is slapping on a coat of paint in an attempt to convince suckers that a design originally intended for "dumb terminals connected to mainframe" actually makes sense for modern embedded "Internet of Things" purposes (it's like gluing a muffler on a horse and pretending it's a "new" kind of motorcycle).

Note that there are things that seem "new" but have nothing to do with the underlying OS. One example is augmented reality (e.g. hololens), which is new for user-space, but barely more than a few tweaks to a few APIs as far as the OS itself is concerned (if I remember right, Microsoft just use Windows10, which is mostly just an evolution of ideas originating from Windows NT from the 1990s, if not earlier).

Also note that a major part of the problem is that anything that is actually new breaks compatibility, so it either dies or gets nerfed until it's the same old stuff we've seen hundreds of times before. An example of this is "The Machine" (from HP) - a bunch of enthusiastic goals reduced to "Oops, we're repurposing that and, um, using Linux. None of the things that made it interesting survived. Sorry". The other part of the problem is difficulty.

Of course this shouldn't be unexpected. When any new technology (fire, wheels, combustion engines, electricity, ..) arrives you get a period of "pioneering" where new ideas and breakthroughs are frequent; but then the technology matures and these things become infrequent.

So...

For some advice that might be useful in practice (assuming this is a university assignment); "waffling" is a valuable skill to learn. Take anything that might be vaguely related and stretch the truth. Mumble. Be vague where it matters and provide unnecessary detail where it doesn't matter. Use words like "instantiationalising" to make your professors eye's glaze over so they can't find any meaning hidden by your words (and let them assume it's their fault for being too busy/distracted to understand, and not your fault). For help, try to read research papers in entirety and then see if you can figure out why it's impossible for anyone to remember anything more than "introduction and conclusion". With practice, a skilled waffler can fill 10+ pages without actually saying anything at all.